# How to change cells height and not to lose them out of sight?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UITableView` with two view modes: normal and simple. In Normal mode cell height is 125 in Simple 75.

When I update rows with:

```
[self reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

and setup new height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    switch (self.mode) {
        case Simple:
            return 75.f;
            break;
        default:
        case Normal:
            return 125.f;
            break;
    }
}
```

all cells that were previously visible, leave the field of view because count of them is 200+.

Any idea how not to lose them?

Comment: But you're not changing the cell height with that code, are you?

Comment: sorry, please see the updated description.